# Display HTML string as read-only formatted text in view

Tags: html, css, angularjs, razor

I have some text being sent from my angular controller to my view that I wish to display as formatted text, and not as HTML.. for the sake of this example, I will use the following code which outputs a read-only textarea but displays the html tags instead of formatting.

```
<div class="well" ng-repeat="field in model.viewFields">
    {{field.Name}} 
    <textarea disabled="true" style="height: 200px; width: 100%; resize: none">{{field.Value}}</textarea>
</div>
```

What can I swap the textarea with to show my {{field.Value}} html as formatted text?

Comment: Why not use <code> or <pre>?

Comment: Maybe try a div with contentEditable to true ? http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/XNkDx/

Comment: @cyrbil im wanting it to be readonly

Comment: @Diodeus tried them both there but the tags are still being displayed even with <code>{{field.Value}}</code> in a new div

Comment: My bad, didn't saw you disable textarea.
From angular I see a [sanitize function](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize) that may fit your needs.

Comment: @cyrbil just what i needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyones future reference, [cyrbil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/956660/cyrbil) pointed out that angulars sanitize function parses the html for you.

You can use [ng-bind-html](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml):

```
<div class="well" ng-repeat="field in model.viewFields">
    {{field.Name}} 
<div ng-bind-html="field.Value" style="height: 200px; width: 100%;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad you put that answer, i'm not used to angular and wasn't able to create a nice example on how to use :)